# DOCKER, HOW TO CONNECT 2 CONTAINER

Tags: ruby, mongodb, docker, containers

i maked a ruby script which is connected with mongoDB, i want to dockerize script and database, and connect them.
i dockerize mongo and create script image throught dockerfile. but when i launch `docker run my_ruby_script` the connection with db failed with error: "`WARN -- : MONGODB |ERROR checking 127.0.0.1:27017: Mongo::Error::SocketError:Errno:ECONNREFUSED:connection refused`", i start mongo container at first and later launch docker run on ruby script,that contains  `Mongo::Client.new(['127.0.0.1:27017'])` <- (this is part of code)

Comment: You have to [publish](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish) port `27017` on the host, otherwise you won't be able to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to connect to 127.0.0.1 which is a loop back ip that directs to the running container instead of the MongoDB container.

To fix it you should create a network the both of the containers are part of it and connect to MongoDB with it.

```bash
docker network create my-network
docker run -d --network my-network --name my-mongo mongo
docker run -d --network my-network <your_script_image>
```

The client IP should be `my-mongo` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

```
Mongo::Client.new(['my-mongo:27017'])
```

Comment: i tried but terminal say me "WARN -- : MONGODB | Error checking my_mongo:27017: sockerError: getaddrinfo : temporary failure in name resolution "

Comment: The address from the terminal and from the docker container should be different.
The solution I wrote will only work when you run both the script and the database on the same docker network, not from the terminal.

If you also want to access it from the terminal run the MongoDB like this:
`docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --network my-network --name my-mongo mongo`
then access your mongo with `127.0.0.1:27017` from your terminal and `my-mongo:27017` from the script.

Comment: notice that the container name is `my-mongo` not `my_mongo`.

Comment: ok thanks, and if i have mongoDB classic(no container) and the ruby script (container)? how do connect them? i try to launch from terminal docker run <my_ruby_img> but doesnt work, and the connection string is client ù= Mongo::Client.new(['127.0.0.1:27017'])

Comment: if they both run on the same machine try setting the MongoDB connection host to: `host.docker.internal:27017`

Comment: inside ruby script? for example: "client= Mongo::Client.new([host.docker.internal:27017']) " ?

Comment: Yes, this will work when the ruby runs inside docker container and the mongodb on the docker host.

Comment: [host.docker.internal - explain](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds-for-all-platforms)

[port-mapping](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#port-mapping)

Comment: one question: i try to connect ruby container with mongo, container port is for example 27017 and mongo port is 27017, but why, when i launch docker run -p 27017:27017 from terminal, i says me Error checking 127.0.0.1:27017:Mongo::Error::socketError::errno::econnrefused

Comment: This is a different question and need more info. Like show the exact command, the code etc... is the other question solved?

Comment: i follow your suggestion but dont work, and later i changed way, i decided to dont dockerize mongoDb, only ruby script have container

Comment: but when i do this, i have port problem, in mongo config file i set port:27017 and bindIP: 127.0.0.1, and later i set docker port at 27017, but when launch: "docker -p 27017:27107 ruby_image", terminal say me a problem that before i wrote

Comment: Can you write the exact command you run and the code used to connect to MongoDB?

Comment: docker run -p 27107:27107 ruby_image. and the code to connect to mongo is: client= Mongo::client.new(['127.0.0.1:27107], :database => DB_test')

Comment: try running
`docker run --network host <ruby_image>`

Comment: it works, but when i run "docker ps", doesnt show any container, how it possible?

Comment: maybe the container is exited, try `docker ps -a`

Comment: it say me "Exited(0) "

Comment: It means that you container is finished running successfully.

Comment: so strange, why this container is formed by a ruby script that write thousands of data in mongoDB, and in the Db i dont see anything

Comment: You'll need to debug your script to figure that out.

Comment: the script works, but the problem seems mongoDB connection

Comment: i suppose that is the only problem, because script work and docker too, but i dont understand why doesnt work.

Comment: i set the correct ports, in the mongoDB conf i choose 0.0.0.0 IP and in the script i connect this with 127.0.0.1

Comment: and when i run program i have a deamon error: "driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint"